# Why use curr = curr.right in LeetCode Kth Smallest Element in a BST?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

So I was solving this LeetCode question https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-smallest-element-in-a-bst/

The solution for this question is

```
class Solution:
    def kthSmallest(self, root: TreeNode, k: int) -> int:
        stack = []
        curr = root

        while stack or curr:
            while curr:
                stack.append(curr)
                curr = curr.left
            curr = stack.pop()
            k -= 1
            if k == 0:
                return curr.val
            curr = curr.right
```

The one thing I don't understand here is why we using

> curr = curr.right

in the last line, what's it's importance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution performs an in-order traversal of the tree. Here are the reasons why that last statement is needed:

- Without it, the only possible navigation would be to go left, as then there is no code that ever visits a right child of a node.
- Without it, the next iteration of the loop would push *the same node* that was popped from the stack, back on the stack, and after the loop it gets popped again. This means the `pop` call will *always* pop the *same* node. The only possible return value is the node with the *least* value.
- The meaning of putting a node on the stack is: "we're now going to the left, but please remind me to actually visit this node later, and then move to the right". When a node is *popped* from the stack, that time has come: we *visit* it (by reducing the value of `k`), and then move to the right, so that also that node's right subtree gets visited.